# iTextSharp: Any support for .Net 6?

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I'm using iTextSharp in the .Net 6 application. At the time of build the application getting the error,

```
Package 'iTextSharp 5.5.13.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp#supportedframeworks-body-tab shows only .NET Framework support. You need to ask the authors for .NET support...